# how to set the minimum height for UIScrollView with autolayout in iOS

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, autolayout

My requirement is that: In my login view,

- when it is landscape,  all view are can be scrolled; when it is portrait, no scrolled.
- when portrait, the `email` textfield must be 30px margin to the `Top Layout Guide`
- when portrait, the `login` button must be 30px margin to the `Bottom Layout Guide`
- every view should be in the scroll view.

*In fact, there is a large logo on the top , I don't want to reduce the size of logo when it is landscape, so I use scrollview. I hope logo and textfield on the top of scrollview, login on the bottom of the scrollview*

Now the question is: **How can I set the minimum height of scroll view**

following is my trouble:

- as there is `iphone4s` and `iphone5/6`, so the height of screen is different
- as there is landscape and portrait, the height of navigation bar and the status bar is changed, so I can't set the minimum height of `ScrollView.contentView = Screen_Height`

what can i do ???

I've upload my test project [here](https://github.com/ygweric/ScrollViewAutoLayoutDemo), you can modify directly so that it can save your time. Thanks.

Comment: Is there any issue if you set your button to be fixed 30 from bottom layout guide in both portrait and landscape ?

Comment: Means button not scroll in landscape mode. Rest of the criteria mentioned in your question is working as I have modified your code.

Comment: @BhadreshMulsaniya Thanks, I wish every views in the scroll view, in fact , there will be a large logo image on the top, when it is landscape, I don't want to reduce the size of logo, so I use the scroll view.